# Upgrading magento templates from CE 1.3 to 1.7

Tags: magento, themes, upgrade

I’m upgrading my two magento websites from magento CE 1.3 to 1.7. I have a fresh install of 1.7 running both sites and everything’s working fine.

The themes used in 1.3 are not compatible to those in 1.7 so I’d like to know if there is any way to import those themes other than re-writing them to 1.7

I've read here that the best way to go would be by doing incremental upgrades up to version 1.7 but I'm not sure which will take longer.

Thanks.

Jose

Comment: I believe a lot of class names were changed between 1.3 and 1.4 particularly. I understood the point of incremental upgrades is for two reasons: the data - it will update it for you one step at a time and you can find issues, and modules - you can see at which step they break.

Comment: Hi Alex, I've decided to create new themes for both websites. We're doing a major restyling and it's a chance to get in to the magento theme thing :) Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3):

steps to glory:

- turn off all local and community extensions
- turn on default theme
- upgrade version by version to latest
- compare your theme edited files and layout files with diff tool like winmerge , changes etc and migrate to latest structure
- turn on extensions one by one and debug

in mean time if it is hardly customized theme then merging it can take all day so you have to weight if making everything from scratch is faster way

Comment: Hi Anton, I've decided to create new themes for both websites. We're doing a major restyling and it's a chance to get in to the magento theme thing :) Thanks for your comment.